# how to pass a class to renderer process using context bridge

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rust, electron, neon-bindings

I have a nodejs module i have created using neon rust, that uses JsBox, and queue async feature. I also have an electron react app, my current mainjs looks like this:

```
function createWindow() {
    const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: true,
            webSecurity: false,
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    })
    mainWindow.loadURL(
        isDev ? "http://localhost:3000" : `file://${path.join(__dirname, "../build/index.html")}`
    )

    // Open the DevTools.
    // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
}
```

In preloadjs i have mapped the module to a class like this:

```
const shinny_spoon_service = require('../../shiny-spoon-service/lib/index')
class Cracker {
    constructor(hash, threads, callback) {
        this._cracker = shinny_spoon_service.cracker_new(hash, threads, callback)
    }
    get_counter() {
        return shinny_spoon_service.get_counter(this._cracker)
    }
    cracker_crack_using_password_file(algorithm,file_path,buff_size){
        return shinny_spoon_service.cracker_crack_using_password_file(this._cracker,algorithm,file_path,buff_size)
    }
}
```

when i pass the class to the renderer process using the context bridge

```
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    "api",
    {
        shiny_spoon: shinny_spoon_service,
        nativeImage: nativeImage,
        Cracker: Cracker,
        send: (channel, data) => {
            // whitelist channels
            let validChannels = ["getFile", "open-error-dialog"];
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, data);
            }
        },
        receive: (channel, func) => {
            let validChannels = ["result-get-file", 'opened-error-dialog'];
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender` 
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, args) => func(event, args));
            }
        },
        sendSync: (channel, data) => {
            // whitelist channels
            let validChannels = ["getFile", "saveFile", "chooseFile"];
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                let result = ipcRenderer.sendSync(channel, data);
                return result
            }
        },
    }
)
```

[I get the Error as shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nq2cw.png)
I would like to interact with the Class from the renderer process, but i don't know how to go about this

Comment: Please do not post images of code or errors, but instead provide them as text! https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors